# Get File Download dialog instead of loading page

Tags: jquery, coldfusion, download

I have the following code, which launches a coldfusion page in a new window

```
$(".productDetailLink").click(function(e) {
    var listings_clickedId = $(this).attr("id")
    var product_id = listings_clickedId.split("^")[1]
    openWindow("/popupDetail.cfm?entity=products&product_id=" + product_id,"detail","width=900,height=600,left=200,top=50,scrollbars=yes");
})
```

I'm pretty sure it wasn't doing this before but instead of opening the page, it launches a file download dialog box, asking me if I want to download the page, instead of just launching the page.

Any help greatly appreciated.

```
function openWindow(url,windowName,winatts){
        var windowName = windowName || 'NewWindow';
        var winatts = winatts || 'width=800,height=600,left=200,top=50,scrollbars=yes';
        window.open(url,windowName,winatts);
    }
```

Comment: Post the content of `popupDetail.cfm`, most likely it's not the jQuery that's an issue, but rather you a response header (perhaps implied) in the .cfm file that browser is interpreting as something to download instead of display.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have access to the cold fusion code?  Am I understanding you correctly that you **want** a download box to show?

If you have access to the ColdFusion server and can modify the response headers to send something like:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=fileName.ext
```

It should prompt for a download box.

Answer (score 0):

```
function openWindow(url,windowName,winatts){
        var windowName = windowName || 'NewWindow';
        var winatts = winatts || '_blank,width=800,height=600,left=200,top=50,scrollbars=yes';
        window.open(url,windowName,winatts);
    }
```

Comment: No, that doesn't do it. I also need it to pop up.

Comment: Also, you should accept answers to your questions if you've found them to be useful(See there is a tick there) and also use upvotes. It will help you get more answers.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with my popup script (I've edited my post to show it). That isn't the issue. I'll tick the box when I get a useful answer.